# Why following animation doesn't work as expected in different broswers

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I have the following animation with `svg`, but they handled completely different on safari and chrome.

```js
let time;
document.querySelector('text').addEventListener('animationstart', () => time = performance.now())
document.querySelector('text').addEventListener('animationend', () => console.log(performance.now() - time))
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: black;
  }
}

text {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: draw 5s forwards;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<svg>
 <text fill='none'  x="50%" y="50%"  text-anchor="middle" stroke="black" stroke-width="5.5" font-size="110">Example</text>
 </svg>
```

On safari, the animation will finish animating the `stroke-dashoffset:0` almost close to the JS event print the finished ( 5s which I set), but on chrome, the animation will finish much faster (about 3 or 2 s).
It will wait for several seconds for the `animationend` event to fire.

Also, the `fill` property on safari will not work at all.

What looks like in safari (with no `fill` black):
[image]

My questions:

Why the two broswers handle  animation differently and why the `fill` doesn't work as expected in Safari?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For the `fill` issue, Safari will simply refuse to animate from `none`, while other browsers will use a discrete animation, as required by the specs. This will switch from `none` to `black` directly, at the middle of the animation time.
If you want a smooth transition then begin with a `fill` value of `transparent`.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("middle of anim");
}, 2500);
```

```css
rect {
  animation: anim 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes anim {
  to {
    fill: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect fill="none" width="50" height="50" />
  <rect fill="transparent" x="60" width="50" height="50" />
</svg>
```

For the `dashoffset` issue... that's a bit more complex. The value `1000` seems to correspond to Safari's computed path-length for this text, while other browsers have it closer to `500`.

```js
let time;
document.querySelector('text').addEventListener('animationstart', () => time = performance.now())
document.querySelector('text').addEventListener('animationend', () => console.log(performance.now() - time))
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: black;
  }
}

text {
  stroke-dasharray: 500; /* will draw half of the stroke in Safari */
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  animation: draw 5s forwards;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text fill="transparent"  x="50%" y="50%"  text-anchor="middle" stroke="black" stroke-width="5.5" font-size="110">Example</text>
</svg>
```

The proper solution for this case would be to compute the text's path length, but [there is still no API that allows to do that](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/221). So the best in your case is to either convert your text to actual path data before-hand, either to use a web-font, analyze it through a library like [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js), and get the text info from there, though I didn't test this solution to see if Safari would match the library's results... so if you can, go with the `<path>` solution.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I am a little bit confused by your statement "The value 1000 seems to correspond to Safari's computed path-length for this text, while other browsers have it closer to 500.". I think the default value for all broswers are 0 which is written on documentation???

Comment: Also, for the `either convert your text to actual path data before-hand`, I am a little bit confused with that (newbie here), I would be really appreciated if you could share a very very small example.  I am really interested in that way, but not pretty sure how you did it:/.  Thank you!

Comment: I am talking about the path-length, that you would get from a <path> element with [`getTotalLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength), but this method is not available on <text> elements. Each text and font will produce a different path-length, and apparently, Safari doesn't agree with other UAs as to how this exact text should get computed. As for converting it to an actual path-data, the easiest is probably to use a soft like InkScape or Illustrator, they do offer this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the clarfication,sorry,  lastly, so the reason why chrome animation much faster than safari is because safari only animation the `dashoffset` to about 500, is it correct?